# jquery emulate key press "ctrl and +"

Tags: jquery

I know the technique for zoom the page using the shift of CSS.

I want to make a button for emulate the user that press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> in same time.

In firefox if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> in the same time the page zooms. I want to write a function that I call and I emulate the press of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd>

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done the way you want to do it. You can't emulate key strokes in browser context. You would have to stick with the CSS variant scaling your font-size globally using ems.

Comment: yea, aefxx is right, you cant do that.
you can't simulate these browser specific behavior the same as you can call the .click().  this is for security reasons.

Comment: It will be better to stick with css.Even if u get it working somehow it will work in windows but not in MAC coz there you press cmd, not ctrl.