# Simulate user keypress to zoom screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, client-side

Is there any way of simulating a keypress of Ctrl+'+' (to zoom in the page) without any user interference?

Is it possible to do it using Flash?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267890/jquery-emulate-key-press-ctrl-and

Answer (score 0):

Not with pure javascript no - if JavaScript were allowed to access controls or functions outside the context of the document that would be a huge security risk. You'll need to simulate the effect with a CSS change of some sort.

Comment: Problem is, I need to zoom the parent page of an iframe, I have only control over the iframe

Comment: Sorry that's not possible - as you've discovered you can't even access the parent page. The same restrictions will stop you accessing the browser it's self too - you need to find another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Bulk it actually is possible to access the parent window. It's just a pain and not worth the effort.

Comment: @Or W good luck Bulk is correct it is a violation and can not be done. Try another approach

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [CSS Zoom](http://htmlcssjavascript.com/css/using-css-zoom-and-css-transforms-for-a-better-increase-text-size-button/), which does pretty much what you described.

Comment: Problem is, I need to zoom the parent page of an iframe, I have only control over the iframe

Comment: @Or W What's with you and the iframes:D Anyways, do you mean that your code runs inside another window that embeds your site as an iframe?

Comment: Then, sadly, I have to answer that this is also impossible without having control over the parent window due to security limitations implemented in browsers.