# Simulate Holding Ctrl Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keydown, multi-select

I'm currently trying to change the default behaviour of a multiselect element, so that a user can select and deselect multiple values, without having to press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key all the while.

I found a simple solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641729/how-to-avoid-the-need-for-ctrl-click-in-a-multi-select-box-using-javascript), but this does not work in ie8 (because in ie, the `onmousedown` [does not apply to option elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536944%28VS.85%29.aspx#feedback)).

But I figured, that one could just simulate a pressed control key, whenever the mouse hovers over a multiselect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').hover(function(e) {
        var kde = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        kde.ctrlKey = true;  //something like this
        kde.keyCode = 17;    //or this - i don't know
        $(e.target).trigger(kde);        
    });
});
```

Why does this not work?

- Is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key directly being released again?
- Is something wrong with the code?
- Am I missing something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simulate such events by programmatically pushing keyboard buttons, just like you can't produce a capital A by simulating the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while the user pushes the <kbd>a</kbd> key on their keyboard. Besides, even if it *would* work it wouldn't work: on Macs you press <kbd>cmd</kbd>, not <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, to select multiple elements.

So unfortunately you'll have to drop this approach and look for other options.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, someone said so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267890/jquery-emulate-key-press-ctrl-and). But I thought it might still work, as this does not invoke a browser function (right?). Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a check box for each of your items, rather than a multi select control.

It is easier in code to write functions which uncheck the others when a new one is selected than to prevent this default behaviour.

Comment: Yes checkboxes would solve the problem with the control key. But as there are so many values in this specific select, checkboxes would be impractical for the user. Thanks anyway

Comment: Could you not put the very long list of checkboxes into your own scrollable div, effectively creating your own list control?

Comment: While that's possible, I don't think that's better than the native control (with it's drawbacks..)